# Cannot convert value of type 'Array<String>?' to specified type 'Array<String>?'

Tags: swift2

I have an array that's receiving values of type `Int` and I want to return an array of `String` after performing some transformation on the values.

They look like this:

```
var ints: Array<Int> = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var strings: Array<String> = Array<String>()
```

The mapping that I'm performing on each array:

```
func convertToStrings(array: Array<Int>?) -> Array<String>? {
    var stringResult: Array<String>? = nil

    if let x = array {
        stringResult = x.map { "Transformed: \($0)" }
    }

    return stringResult
}
```

Setting this up as a global function works but I'd like to attach it to an object, perhaps as an extension to Array. When I try it like so:

```
extension Array {
    static func convertToStrings(array: Array<Int>?) -> Array<String>? {
        var stringResult: Array<String>? = nil

        if let x = array {
            stringResult = x.map { "Transformed: \($0)" }
        }

        return stringResult
    }
}
```

with this usage:

```
var result: Array<String>? = Array.convertToStrings([1, 2])
print("result: \(result)")
```

I get this error:

> error: cannot convert value of type 'Array?' to specified type
>   'Array?'

I'm not sure why this error is getting produced.

What's a good way to encapsulate this function into less of a global domain space and attach it a more sensible scope?

EDIT: Part 2

I'd like to make the reverse of the above function, where I take an Array of String types and convert to Array of Int when the count of characters for each string is greater than 0. However, I can't seem to do that because the only protocol similar to _IntegerType is _CocoaStringType.

A few things:

1. I'm not sure if I should be using a type with an underscore
   prefix
2. _CocoaStringType does not inherit from anything that
   allows for string.characters.count to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are for all types so your extension will apply no matter what the array contains. I recommend creating a protocol to which the extension conforms to avoid calling for example this extension method on a [UIView] array or a [String] array which will not make sense. The following conforms to _IntegerType but you can use your own protocol too

```
extension Array where Element: _IntegerType {
    static func convertToStrings(array: [Element]?) -> [String]? 
    {
        var stringResult: [String]?

        if let x = array {
            stringResult = x.map { "Transformed: \($0)" }
        }

        return stringResult
    }
}
```

Since you asked, You can do the opposite (convert string array elements to Int as follows

```
extension Array where Element: StringLiteralConvertible {
    static func convertToInt(array: [Element]?) -> [Int]? 
    {
        var intResult: [Int]?
        if let x = array {
            intResult = x.map{Int("\($0)")!}
        }
        return intResult
    }
}
var r:[Int]? = Array.convertToInt(["1", "4"])
print(r) // this will print "Optional[1, 4]\n"
```

Comment: What type would you use if you want to go the other way, converting from Int to String, when string length is non-empty? String is a struct and couldn't find a corresponding protocol, similar to _IntegerType.

Comment: Do you mean from string to int?

Comment: I added that in my answer

Comment: Thank you. One last question related to this. I added a filter before the map function to perform a transformation only if the string is non-empty. let filtered = x.filter{ (element: String) in element.characters.count >  0 }. But this elicits the error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". What's a good way to be able to use String's extension methods?

Comment: Again, the extension is on array so the elements are type Element so element:String will not make sense.
let filtered = x.filter{ (element: Element) in 
                (element as? String)?.characters.count > 0 
            }

Answer (score 0):

A solution is an `Array` extension constrained to `CustomStringConvertible` (former `Printable`) and it's much easier – and more reasonable – to declare all types as non optional

```
extension Array where Element: CustomStringConvertible {
  static func convertToStrings(array: [Element]) -> [String]
  {
    return array.map { "Transformed: \($0)" }
  }
}

let result = Array.convertToStrings([1, 2])
print("result: \(result)")
```

Comment: How would this ensure that Array element type should not be an unexpected type and instead only Integer?

Comment: The extension accepts everything which can be used in a String interpolation. The compiler will complain about anything else.